# How do I open `.localstorage` files from Local Storage folder?

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage

I want to open Local Storage files of Google Chrome. I found where Chrome stores them, but I could not open them.

How can I do that?

Comment: `brew install sqlitebrowser`

Comment: what is that, where does it go/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can browse `.localstorage` files by a SQLite browser, such as the open source program called [sql-lite database browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/)

On macOS, you can install via Brew: `brew install sqlite`.

Comment: I did `brew install --cask db-browser-for-sqlite`