# Where does Google Chrome save LocalStorage from Extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage

I just had to format my Windows 7 system and start over, I made some backups of certain files/folders though and I am trying to find out where Google Chrome stores users data that extensions save, like which folder(s) I could look in to maybe recover some data for a certain extension I had?

Answer (score 38):

Looks like it's `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage`.

[image: This looks about right...]
(click for larger version)

Comment: for linux ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Local Storage

Comment: Is this documented? If I backup this folder and try to restore it next time, would it work?

Comment: For my developed extension loaded as CRX, the localstorage is on the `\Local Storage\leveldb` directory on the `.ldb` files. This post contains info about that files https://superuser.com/questions/1065771/what-embedded-database-format-is-used-by-this-chrome-extension

Answer (score 14):

As an update, the folder in the marked answer was no longer working for me. First I found out where the folder my Chrome profile was being stored by going to `chrome://version` and opening the location for Profile Path.

Once there, the local storage items I set in my location were stored in:

`\Local Extension Settings\__extensionID__`

Comment: Could you share more please?

Comment: @AlexS Sure, what would you like me to expand on?

Comment: @NoR, Odd, `Local Extension Settings` folder is empty  for me.....

Comment: +1 for stating that `chrome://version` gives you your Profile Path. PS: In January 2017 on macOS LocalStorage SQLite DBs can be found in `<chrome_profilepath>/Local Storage`.

Answer (score 11):

On Mac OS X it's stored in your Chrome *user profile* directory:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/<user-profile>/Local Storage/
```

commonly, the default with only one profile, that is:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage/
```

---

**Update:** Thanks to @Barmar's comment that this has changed.

LocalStorage is now saved in the `leveldb` subdirectory as a set of `.ldb` files. The default path is now:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage/leveldb
```

On ***my*** system the leveldb directory was created on Oct 8 2017 which is about a month after the 61.0.3163 release.

Comment: It looks like this has changed a bit now. None of the files in that directory have been modified since 2017, but there's now a subdirectory `leveldb` with a bunch of `.ldb` files. Unfortunately, it's no longer set up as separate files for each domain.

Answer (score 4):

Some data from the extensions can be found in `Local Storage` folders (for each profile), these files have `.localstorage`/`.localstorage-journal` extensions and are in SQLite format. However, it's best to back up all files within `Local Storage` folder. See: [How do I open `.localstorage` files from Local Storage folder?](https://superuser.com/q/355218/87805)

Some other data are stored in [LevelDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LevelDB) format under `IndexedDB` folders (for each profile). The file extension is `.ldb`, however, all files are needed from the `*.indexeddb.leveldb` folders in order to have consistent data.

See also:

- [How can I modify data stored by Chrome extensions?](https://superuser.com/q/942392/87805)
- [What embedded database format is used by this Chrome extension?](https://superuser.com/q/1065771/87805)
- [What is store in Local Storage used for in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/q/356494/87805)
- [How to access Google Chrome's IndexedDB/LevelDB files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35074659/55075)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows XP, Vista and 7 (at least) this will be the path:
C:\Documents and Settings\administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage

Make sure you adapt the user part ("administrator") of the path to reflect your username.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the path in `Answer` is not working any more,
use this path on Win7,8,10

`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases`

Comment: Tip: Use `%LOCALAPPDATA%` instead of everything before `Google`