# What are the impacts of moving Local Storage from one machine to the other?

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage

In [this other question](https://superuser.com/q/507536/90117) I learned where the local storage is physically located on the disk.

Suppose I copy this whole folder from one machine and paste it on other machine, running same version of Chrome. What will be the impacts? Does Chrome associate the local storage with the local machine?

I know I can try it myself but using Chrome as my main browser prefer not to experiment with it too much, risking in bringing it down.

One usage of this (if no negative impacts) is to synchronize local-storage based websites between different machines e.g. when inside a network it will be possible to write scripts that copy this folder.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but as it stands it _might_ get closed. Could you specify what you're hoping it will do/what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Tanner fair enough, added one possible usage.