# Chrome won't clear application storage

Tags: google-chrome

I'm developing a progressive web app which I'm running in Google Chrome 79.0.3945.130

Suddenly I started getting errors, which I traced to calls to local storage - it was returning a DOMException with error code 22 (QuotaExceededError)

Looking in the application tab I can see that the quota was indeed full, with IndexedDB taking up most of the space:

[image: Chrome application tab]

However, nothing I try actually clears the storage. I can look in the IndexedDB and it says there are 0 entries. I can even remove the database completely. I've also tried the "clear site data" button with all options ticked. But still the storage used doesn't change. What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've still no idea why it wasn't working but I've found a workaround thanks to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/507536/where-does-google-chrome-save-localstorage-from-extensions) question.

- Exit Chrome
- Delete the following folder:
  %LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB[url_of_app].indexeddb.leveldb
- Restart Chrome