# What embedded database format is used by this Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, database, chromium, facebook

Chrome extension [F.B. Purity](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fb-purity-clean-up-facebo/ncdlagniojmheiklojdcpdaeepochckl) writes its data at `~/.config/chromium/Default/Local Extension Settings/ncdlagniojmheiklojdcpdaeepochckl/000003.log` (not a log file despite its name).

This file is a kind of database that contains among other things a big JSON string. Here is the beginning of the file seen in vim:

```
????C^@^A^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^A^Kfbpfirstrun)"Fri Apr 15 2016 16:59:41 
GMT+0900 (JST)"??[E7^@^A^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^A^Rfbplastupdatecheck^V"
1460707185929:14.7.0"??U/7^@^A^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^A^Ylastfriendcheck-
631501256^O"1460707180223"0?wB3^?^B^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^A^Xoldfriendstore-
631501256??^G"{\"27333\":\"
```

... at which point the big JSON string starts.
Same beginning of the file as hexadecimal:

```
C4 C4 3F 81 43 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
00 00 01 0B 66 62 70 66 69 72 73 74 72 75 6E 29 22
46 72 69 20 41 70 72 20 31 35 20 32 30 31 36 20 31
36 3A 35 39 3A 34 31 20 47 4D 54 2B 30 39 30 30 20
28 4A 53 54 29 22 AE B6 5B 45 37 00 01 02 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 12 66 62 70 6C 61 73 74
75 70 64 61 74 65 63 68 65 63 6B 16 22 31 34 36 30
37 30 37 31 38 35 39 32 39 3A 31 34 2E 37 2E 30 22
A6 C0 55 2F 37 00 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
00 00 01 19 6C 61 73 74 66 72 69 65 6E 64 63 68 65
63 6B 2D 36 33 31 35 30 31 32 35 36 0F 22 31 34 36
30 37 30 37 31 38 30 32 32 33 22 30 AC 77 42 33 7F
02 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 18 6F 6C
64 66 72 69 65 6E 64 73 74 6F 72 65 2D 36 33 31 35
30 31 32 35 36 E3 C5 07 22 7B 5C 22 32 37 33 33 33
5C 22 3A 5C 22
```

**QUESTION**: What kind of database format is that?

SQLitebrowser refuses to open it. The Ubuntu `file` command just says `data`. My goal is to extract the first JSON string from that file. Using latest Chromium.

Comment: Looks like a Chrome-specific format, [probably this one](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). You're likely better off using a hex editor to help figure it out.

Comment: @Ouroborus: You link to an API, now we need to find out how this API stores its data internally. I am using a hex editor now for experiments, but the task needs to be automated, so a graphical/human editor won't do.

Comment: Chrome is mostly open source under [The Chromium Projects](https://www.chromium.org/Home). Perhaps that's a good place to figure out how the file is constructed.

Comment: Related: [How to access Google Chrome's IndexedDB/LevelDB files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35074659/55075)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It’s [LevelDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LevelDB), a key-value store.

You can use NodeJS and [levelup](https://github.com/Level/levelup) to access the data:

```
var levelup = require("levelup");
var db = levelup("path/to/directory");
db.createReadStream().on("data", data => console.log(data.key, " => ", data.value));
```

(levelup requires [leveldown](https://github.com/level/leveldown/) to be installed for accessing on-disk databases.)

Answer (score 3):

The files are in [LevelDB format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LevelDB) developed by Google and the code is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/leveldb).

Potentially you can use [`leveldb-json`](https://github.com/nisaacson/leveldb-json) utility to export the data by pointing to the `.indexeddb.leveldb` folder, however, you would need to implement a compatible comparator first (as Chrome provides its own comparator implementation) in order to inspect Chrome's Indexed DB leveldb instances as per information at [How to access Google Chrome's IndexedDB/LevelDB files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35074659/55075)

Comment: Project homepage link is dead. :(